# Standard algorithm for accumulating a container into a string with a delimiter separating the entries?

Tags: c++, std

I am looking for a standard library equivalent of this code for accumulating elements of an std container into a string with a delimiter separating consecutive entries:

```
string accumulate_with_delimiter( vector<string> strvect, string delimiter )
{
    string answer;
    for( vector<string>::const_iterator it = strvect.begin(); it != strvect.end(); ++it ) 
    {
        answer += *it;
        if( it + 1 != strvect.end() ) 
        {
            answer += delimiter;
        } 
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Such code seems to be very common: printing out an array with delimiter " ", or saving into a CSV file with delimiter ",", etc. Therefore it's likely that a piece of code like that made its way into a standard library. std::accumulate comes close, but doesn't have a delimiter.

Comment: `std::accumulate` can do it if you pass it a custom predicate function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the standard C++ library has a nice approach to delimiting sequences. I typically end up using something like

```
std::ostringstream out;
if (!container.empty()) {
    auto end(container.end());
    std::copy(container.begin(), --end, std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, ", "));
    out << *end;
}
```

Using `std::accumulate()` has a similar problem of although with the first element rather than the last element. Using a custom add function, you could use it something like this:

```
std::string concat;
if (!container.empty()) {
    auto begin(container.begin());
    concat = std::accumulate(++begin, container.end(), container.front(),
        [](std::string f, std::string s) { return f + ", " + s; });
}
```

In both cases the iterators need to be moved to another element. The code uses temporary objects when moving the iterator because the `container` may use pointers as iterator in which case a pre-increment or pre-decrement on the result from `begin()` or `end()` doesn't work.

Comment: `next(container.begin())` ?

Comment: @MSalters: yes, `next()` would work. I'm not used to these - they must be new (possibly C++03, though... ;)

Answer (score 1):

`std::accumulate` might be the correct answer, but you need the version which takes a custom adder. You can then provide your own lambda.

Remember to pass `front()` as the first value to accumulate, and start adding at `begin() + 1`. And test for empty vectors first of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is one in the recent Standard Library or not, but there is always [`boost::algorithm::join(strvec, delimiter)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/join.html).